# What are the ideal soil conditions for planting giant sequoia saplings?

Tags: trees, soil, seeds, planting

I've already germinated giant sequoia (*Sequoiadendron giganteum*) seeds for 6 weeks.

What's the ideal soil conditions for planting the saplings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Giant Sequoia Landscape Questions](http://www.giant-sequoia.com/faqs/giant-sequoia-landscape-questions/):

> Sequoias require moist, rich, balanced ph, and well-drained soil. Permanently swampy or muddy soil will not work.

Based on this, you should make sure your soil is neither sandy nor hard clay... you'll want a [loam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loam) type of soil.

Answer (score 1):

Study their native range.
Giant Sequoia (Sequoiadendron Giganteum) grows in a sandy loam soil in California it's a granitic residual.... Though adaptable to many soil conditions You can replicate it. If you have silt/clay soil it's fine. Break it up real good and mix it with 25% sand with granite dust (a countertop maker which cuts granite will give it to you), 40% potting mix/compost blend and 40% the soil you broke up. Well drained.
Another recommendation is to give your tree a mycorrhizal inoculation.The  mycorrhizal  fungus  basically  serves  as  an  extension  of  the  plant  root  system,  exploring  soil  far  beyond  the  roots'  reach  and  transporting  water  and  nutrients  to  the  roots; by producing micro filaments thousands of times smaller than a normal root, these filaments soak up nutrients like a sponge and give it to the plant, In exchange for a steady diet of sugars. For example: Pine Tree on the right, same age but grown without a myco inoculation
Tree on the left, Same Age grown WITH.
[image]